# все работает правильно,но мне интересно почему для вывода в условии пишется:if (isset($value[1]))?

Tags: php, файлы, вывод

Всё работает правильно, но мне интересно, почему для вывода в условии пишется: `if (isset($value[1]))`?

```
<?php 
    $userf = fopen('users.txt', 'r') or die("Unable to open file!");
        $users = fread($userf, filesize('users.txt'));
        fclose($userf);
        $list = [];
        $list = explode("--#@@#--", $users);
        foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
            $list[$key] = explode('|', $value);
        }
?>
```

…

```
<?php
    foreach ($list as $value){
        echo "<tr>";
        if (isset($value[1])) {
            echo "<td> $value[0]</td><td>   $value[1]</td><td><img src=uploads/".$value[2]." height=150 width=200/></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: я новенький,поэтому если косяки в вопросе извияюсь

Comment: Проверяется или существует переменная, если существует то выводится строка таблицы, если не существует переменной то в таблицу ничего не выводится. Если не было бы этой проверки то в таблице были бы пустые строки.

Comment: аа ,то есть 1 это в смысле true ??

Comment: О боже мой. Прочитайте про массивы

Comment: нет 1  это второй элемент массива `$list`. Почитайте что такое массивы  и циклы в частности `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например массив `$list` у вас будет приблизительно так выглядеть
`Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Имя 1 [2] => адрес изображения 1) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => Имя 2 [2] => адрес изображения 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => Имя 2 [2] => адрес изображения 3 ) 
)`

```
foreach ($list as $value){ //проходим в цикле массив $list. То есть каждый элемент массива по очереди помещаем в переменную $value, таким образом у вас сначала в переменную попадет строка `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Имя 1 [2] => адрес изображения 1)` потом `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => Имя 2 [2] => адрес изображения 2 )` и так далее.
    echo "<tr>"; // выводим тег <tr>
    if (isset($value[1])) { // Проверяется или существует переменная (точнее есть ли в переменной $value которая имеет некий массив данных запись с индексом указанным в "[]" в нашем случае это "1" в массиве это "[1] => Имя 1" в переменной "$value[1]" будет "Имя 1"), если существует то выводится строка таблицы, если не существует переменной (точнее записи под индексом указанным в "[]" в нашем случае это "1" в нашем примере вместо "Имя 1" ничего не будет записано) то в таблицу ничего не выводится. Если не было бы этой проверки то в таблице были бы пустые строки.
        echo "<td> $value[0]</td><td>   $value[1]</td><td><img src=uploads/".$value[2]." height=150 width=200/></td>"; //Выводим столбцы таблицы в которые заносим значение с массива $value[0] то есть элемент масива "[0] => 1" в таблице будет "1", $value[1] то есть элемент масива "[1] => Имя 1" в таблице будет "Имя 1" и $value[2] то есть элемент масива "[2] => адрес изображения 1" в таблице будет "адрес изображения 1".
    }
    echo "</tr>"; // выводим тег </tr>
}
```